# Logical OR in a matlab IF statement?

Tags: matlab, if-statement

I'm trying to utilize a logical OR in an IF statement within MATLAB. Where `TRI` is a 32x2 vector, I want to check if a certain row in `TRI` contains a 28 or 31, if so do some operation.

I can't figure out why this is difficult, the line containing the logic is currently:

```
if (TRI(i,:)==28 || TRI(i,:)==31);
```

Answer (score 3):

OK you want something like

```
if any(TRI(i,:)==28) || any(TRI(i,:)==31)
```

Your original code didn't work because you were comparing vectors `TRI(i,:)` to scalars. Doing `vector==scalar` will give you a vector where each element is the result of `==` with the scalar. Since you are looking for a single match in a row, `any` tells you whether the `==` is true for any element of the vector. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: haven't used or heard of the any() function. noob mistake! thanks so much

Comment: @user2208604 - if this solution solved your problem, please hit the checkmark to officially accept the answer (and reward David for answering you)!